# Injected log4net logs duplicate message to console

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm injecting log4net as follows:

**DI**

```
container.RegisterSingleton<Func<object, ILog>>(instance => {
    return LogManager.GetLogger(instance.GetType());
});
```

**Usage**

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public MyClass(Func<object, ILog> loggerFactory) {
        _logger = loggerFactory(this);
    }
}
```

In the console, I get predictable duplicate messages. The first set of messages prints once, the second set two times, the sixth set six times, etc...

```
4470 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
5953 [5] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 1 / 14 (7.14 %)
6489 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
6489 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
7679 [8] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 2 / 14 (14.29 %)
7679 [8] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 2 / 14 (14.29 %)
8512 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
8512 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
8512 [6] INFO JobManager - Getting pending jobs...
9551 [29] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 3 / 14 (21.43 %)
9551 [29] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 3 / 14 (21.43 %)
9551 [29] DEBUG JobManager - #113: 3 / 14 (21.43 %)
```

Honestly, I'm *not sure why it's even logging to the console* since I don't have that appender configured or enabled, and it does do even when I do comment out `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` and the log4net-related things in the config file. The only appender I'm using is Gibraltar. Note that I'm running this from VS, not debugging, and have tried both Debug and Release configurations with the same result. I added a file appender and **the lines are not duplicated** in the resulting log file.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint to `return LogManager.GetLogger()` just to prove that you don't produce singletons for each request? Just a thought ...

Comment: Why are you injecting a Func and not simply an ILog? I am curious.

Comment: @CodingYoshi So each type can have its own logger. Unless I misunderstand your question...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that another developer had been calling `XmLConfigurator.Configure()` within the constructor of a class which was not properly being injected via DI. So every time the class was instantiated, log4net would be configured again, adding another instance of each configured logger.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the not configured additivity on your loggers:

```
<logger name="myloggername" additivity="false">
```

Comment: Actually I figured this out and will post my answer.